Stuck with the part of string comparison
I have to change the "." parts of the IP address to "[.]" using C++. For example: "1.1.1.1" should be converted to "1[.]1[.]1[.]1".
I tried to solve it using normal for-loop,
string defangIPaddr(string address) {
    for(int i=0;i<address.size();i++)
    {
        if(address[i]==".")
        {
            address[i]="[.]";
        }
    }
    return address;
}

But it throws an error:
Line 6: Char 16: error: no matching function for call to 'strcmp'
6 |             if(strcmp(address[i],"."))
  |                ^~~~~~
/usr/include/string.h:156:12: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'value_type' (aka 'char') to 'const char *' for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &
147 | extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
    |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Can someone please explain what mistake(s) have I made here?

Why not simply build a new string from scratch instead of trying to adjust the original string?  Then you just return the new, built-up string.

To begin with the code you show doesn't match the error you show. Please make sure to show us a proper [mre], and the actual matching error.

If you don't know how to format text in SO, then please don't try. Just copy and paste it. Someone will come along and fix it. On the other hand, when you choose the wrong formatting and insert superfluous characters to "fix it", you get a mess that is just a waste of yours and the editor's time.

As for the problem, address[i] is a single character, while "." is a string (containing two characters). "[.]" is a string as well, containing four characters. How will that even fit in the single character of address[i]?

I am new to SO also didn't know how to edit and stuff so i apologize. Thanks for your comments , i got the answer by using a new string instead of using the existing one and changed the "" to ''.

you are assigning to a single location address[i] more than one character when you do address[i]="[.]";  this will never work.

The errors are that

You are trying to compare a single character address[i] to a string "."
You are trying to stuff four characters into a single character, address[i]="[.]".

Even if you fix those errors so that your code compiles cleanly, your loop is very awkward in that you are increasing the size of the original string if . is found, and at the same time you're looping depending on the size of the string.
Instead of all of this, simply build a new string from the original string by looping over the original string and checking each character to see if it is '.':
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string defangIPaddr(std::string address) 
{
    std::string newString;
    for(auto ch : address)
    {
        if (ch == '.')
            newString += "[.]";
        else
            newString += ch;
    }
    return newString;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << defangIPaddr("1.1.1.1");
}

Output:
1[.]1[.]1[.]1


I upvoted Paul McKenzie’s answer, but you can also accomplish this with regular expressions:
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string ip = "192.168.1.1";
    std::cout
        << ip
        << " --> "
        << regex_replace( ip, std::regex{ "\\." }, "[.]" )
        << "\n";
}


I would use a reusable function to split up a string into substrings (tokenize like function). And then use std::format to creat the output string. Like this
#include <cassert>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>


auto split_string(std::string_view string, std::string_view delimiters)
{
    std::vector<std::string_view> substrings;
    
    if ((string.size() == 0ul))
    {
        return substrings;
    }
    
    if (delimiters.size() == 0ul)
    {
        substrings.emplace_back(string);
        return substrings;
    }

    auto start_pos = string.find_first_not_of(delimiters);
    auto end_pos = start_pos;
    auto max_length = string.length();

    while (start_pos < max_length)
    {
        end_pos = std::min(max_length, string.find_first_of(delimiters, start_pos));

        if (end_pos != start_pos)
        {
            substrings.emplace_back(&string[start_pos], end_pos - start_pos);
            start_pos = string.find_first_not_of(delimiters, end_pos);
        }
    }

    return substrings;
}

std::string defangIPaddr(const std::string_view sv)
{
    auto result = split_string(sv, ".");
    assert(result.size() == 4ul);

    return std::format("{}[.]{}[.]{}[.]{}", result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3]);
}

int main()
{
    std::string_view test{ "192.168.0.1" };
    std::cout << defangIPaddr(test);
}

